# dump yaml file with correct multiline without newline character with Python

Tags: python, yaml

i need to recreate that file in yaml :

```
- account_type: 3
  active: true
  addresses: 
  - address: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
    enabled: true
    username: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
  email: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
  firstname: firstname
  high_score: 0.0
  lastname: lastname
  lists: []
  local: false
  low_score: 0.0
  password1: !!python/unicode 'Deef2fht'
  password2: !!python/unicode 'Deef2fht'
  send_report: true
  signatures: []
  spam_checks: true
  timezone: !!python/unicode 'Europe/Rome'
  username: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
```

so i create this piece of code :

```
import yaml
import random
import string
import sys
email = sys.argv[1]
dominio = email.split("@")
nome = (dominio[0].split("."))[0]
cognome = (dominio[0].split("."))[1]
password = random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(8)])
document = """
  account_type: 3
  active: true
  addresses: 
    address: '"""+email+"""'
    enabled: true
    username: '"""+email+"""'
    email: '"""+email+"""'
  firstname: """+nome+"""
  high_score: 0.0
  lastname: """+cognome+"""
  lists: []
  local: false
  low_score: 0.0
  password1: '"""+password+"""'
  password2: '"""+password+"""'
  send_report: true
  signatures: []
  spam_checks: true
  timezone: 'Europe/Rome'
  username: '"""+email+"""'
"""
yaml.safe_dump(document, open("output.yaml", "w"), default_flow_style=False)
```

but the output is only on a line and for every newline on my document variable i've /n character.
There is a way to do that without print every line on a different variable?

Comment: why do it this way?

Comment: sorry but i'm a newbie of python, i'm searching to find a way and i've found that.

Comment: Newline is `\n`. Is that what you meant to write when you said "_for every newline on my document variable i've /n character_"

Comment: yeah sorry \n not /n

Comment: `yaml.safe_dump` - Serialize a Python object into a YAML stream. `document` - it is just a string object(it's not a `dict` or whatever), so you got what you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using string concatenation, build a dictionary that represents your yml object. Then use `yaml.dump()` to write that back to disk. An easy way to understand how the yaml library works is to load an existing file into a variable, change some values and write it back to disk.

1. Create a foo.yml file with your goal yaml:

   ```
   - account_type: 3
     active: true
     addresses: 
     - address: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
       enabled: true
       username: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
     email: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
     firstname: firstname
     high_score: 0.0
     lastname: lastname
     lists: []
     local: false
     low_score: 0.0
     password1: !!python/unicode 'Deef2fht'
     password2: !!python/unicode 'Deef2fht'
     send_report: true
     signatures: []
     spam_checks: true
     timezone: !!python/unicode 'Europe/Rome'
     username: !!python/unicode 'firstname.lastname@email.com'
   ```
2. Read the file into a variable, explore it's structure, change the username and save a new yml file back to disk.

   ```
   import yaml
   x = {}
   with open('foo.yml', 'r') as my_file:
       x = yaml.load(my_file)

   x[0]['username'] = 'different_user@domain.com'

   with open('new.yml', 'w') as new_file:
       yaml.dump(x, new_file)
   ```

Comment: thanks for your support, if i want to edit `enabled: true` how can i do? because it's a nested level inside this yaml